# How to make a border which wraps around text

Tags: html, css, border

I would like to make a text element have a border around it like this in an upcoming ghost dashboard: [Ghost blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCQFN.png)

I have done this:

```
    border: 10px solid #ffffff;
```

however that works for the height but not the width. The width is a lot wider. I know I could set the width to something however I would like the width to update when the text is changed, so there is always a certain amount of space between the text and box on each side.

I'm not sure how to do this or if it needs JS or if it can be done with pure CSS.

Comment: What do you mean? A border of 10px means 10px thick around every side. Border thickness on the side of an image will be equal to border thickness on the top of the border.

Comment: What is your HTML markup like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are going to want to use padding and `display:inline-block;` on a `span` element in order to do this. For example:

HTML

```
<span>GHOST</span>
```

CSS

```
span {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 10px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will allow the border around the text to shrink and grow depending on the length. It will also keep 10px of space between the border and the letters no matter the size.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDzn2/

Comment: Nice! Just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want the border-width to be included in the css-width?!

you should then try the box-sizing attribute via CSS:

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

The box-sizing CSS property is used to alter the default CSS box model used to calculate widths and heights of elements. It is possible to use this property to emulate the behavior of browsers that do not correctly support the CSS box model specification.
[Source: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing%5d)

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

[Source: [http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/]](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/%5d)

Comment: uhmm.. That didn't work for me. I want the border width to be the same size as whatever text is showing. Do you think you could make a fiddle?